# Value between opening and closing bracket

Tags: regex

I am unable to find pattern for last line since it has sub parenthesis `()`. I am trying to fetch all values between first `(` before `(array['something']` and respective closing parenthesis `)`

Sample Data Set

```
((array['ky'] <@ type_list AND array['Deviceless4D'] <@ value_list)))))

(array['snm'] <@ type_list AND (array['RAQ'] <@ value_list OR array['QQWYR'] <@ value_list)) AND ( array['snm'] <@ type_list AND NOT array['AQ'] <@ value_list)))

( array['ky'] <@ type_list AND NOT array['ASIR'] <@ value_list)))

( array['type_q'] <@ type_list AND NOT array['1.0Q 22QW_%_Driver'] <@ value_list))

(array['snm'] <@ type_list AND (array['HM'] <@ value_list OR array['UA'] <@ value_list OR array['R'] <@ value_list OR array['W'] <@ value_list)) AND ( array['revision'] <@ type_list AND NOT array['SQ1.1'] <@ value_list)))

( array['x_type'] <@ type_list AND NOT array['2.1T 44QAW SN (645222) or (124T)'] <@ value_list)))
```

Below is the regex i am trying:

`r"(?s)\(\s*array\['\w+'\]\s*<@\s*type_list .*?\)"`

But last sample record is giving match like below:

`( array['x_type'] <@ type_list AND NOT array['2.1T 44QAW SN (645222)`

Expected output for last row:

`( array['x_type'] <@ type_list AND NOT array['2.1T 44QAW SN (645222) or (124T)'] <@ value_list)`

Except for last row, rest all records are matching as expected since they dont have sub parenthesis in between.

Comment: Why don't you use a greedy dot? [`.*?` => `.*`](https://regex101.com/r/yPiwtK/1) (but remove `(?s)`)

Comment: Yeah, i did work around, we can close this now. Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew